# "ambiguating new declaration" error for a templated method in a templated class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization, ambiguity

I have written the following earth-shattering application:

```
class SomeA { }; class SomeB { }; class SomeC { };

template <typename A, typename B, typename... Cs>
class Foo {
public:
    template <typename U> static void bar();
};

template <typename U>
void Foo<SomeA, SomeB, SomeC>::bar() { };

int main() { return 0; }
```

When I compile this (gcc 4.9.3 with `-std=c++11`), I get the following error:

```
a.cpp:10:36: error: ambiguating new declaration of ‘static void Foo<SomeA, SomeB, SomeC>::bar()’
 void Foo<SomeA, SomeB, SomeC>::bar() { };
                                    ^
a.cpp:6:36: note: old declaration ‘static void Foo<A, B, Cs>::bar() [with U = U; A = SomeA; B = SomeB; Cs = {SomeC}]’
  template <typename U> static void bar();
                                    ^
```

Why is this an "ambiguating declaration", and how else can I implement bar for all `U`s but for a specific instantiation of `Foo`?

With clang 3.6.2, I get the error:

```
a.cpp:9:1: error: template parameter list matching the non-templated nested type 'Foo<SomeA, SomeB, SomeC>' should be empty ('template<>')
template <typename U>
^        ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I don't really get this either. How am I supposed to template over U if clang wants an empty parameter list?

Comment: I don't know what an "ambiguating new declaration is", but Clang gives a much more helpful error message: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/308fd608ff25e9a3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No idea what *ambiguating new declaration* means, but you're specializing the enclosing class template `Foo`, so you need to indicate that with an empty template parameter list

```
template <>
template <typename U>
void Foo<SomeA, SomeB, SomeC>::bar() { }
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e28e36d7e437402)

Comment: Oh... ahh.... I see. I didn't know you could follow `template<whatever>` immediately with another `template<whatever>`.